# Variance-covariance matrix with multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data:

```
   at_score    atp_1   atp_2   atp_3   g_date  g_id    g_time  ht_diff ht_score    htp_1   htp_2   htp_3
0       0         6      7        8    11/16/18   1      0         0       0          1       2      3
1       13        6      7        9    11/16/18   1      15        2     15           1       2      3
2       20        7      8       10    11/16/18   1      18        2     22           3       4      5
3       40        7      8        6    11/16/18   1      33        5     45           4       1      2
4       65        8      7        6    11/16/18   1      60       -3     62           1       2      3
5        0        6      7        8    11/20/18   2       0        0     0            1       2      3
6       10        9      7        8    11/20/18   2       7       -4     6            4       2      3
7       26        6     10        7    11/20/18   2      24       -1     25           1       5      4
8       40        9      7        8    11/20/18   2      42        5     45           1       2      5
9       65        6      7       10    11/20/18   2      60        5     70           1       5      2
```

where at_score, ht_score are the away & home team's score on a particular date (g_date), in a particular game (g_id), & at a particular time in the game (g_time). ht_diff represents the home team's score differential (ht_score - at_score). Finally, and for my purposes most importantly, atp_1, atp_2, atp_3 are the 3 away players who are playing at that point. htp_1, htp_2, htp_3 are their home team counterparts.

What I'd like to calculate is the variance-covariance matrix for each of the home & away team players based on how the ht_diff, ht_score & at_score changed while they were playing and the players they were playing with. For example away player 6 played with players 7 & 8 for the first 13 minutes of g_id 1 (ht_diff = 2 for this period) & the last 27 minutes (ht_diff = -3).

In the end I have about 2.5 million observations (as well as 10 players playing at a time) so finding a 'easy' to calculate this would be extremely helpful.